# Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for MatTableDataSource: (?)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

In Angular v6, I am using the Angular Material table component. In my unit test, I've already added

```ts
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and

```ts
imports: [ MatDialogModule ]
```

But I'm getting this error:

[image: Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for MatTableDataSource: (?).]

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MatTableDataSource: (?).
  ...
```

Comment: Could you attach your testing file?

Answer (score 0):

Include the following import in your app.module.ts, It will work

`import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';`